# Distinguish different values in @PostMapping, @GetMapping or @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/weblogin", "/mobilelogin" })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public AccessTokenResponseModel login() { // need to distinguish "/weblogin" or "/mobilelogin" }
```

In spring boot, How can I distinguish the post request comes from "/weblogin" or "/mobilelogin"
in login() method?

Comment: May I ask why not declare an extra method just for another URI and have it call the service instead? I think it would be less hassle rather than detecting the URI in controller

Comment: Because there has the same business logic for "/weblogin" and "/mobilelogin" except the webtoken and mobiletoken are different. Aims to avoid the code redundance.

Comment: Then you should get the respective token and then decide from where the request has been received. From your code it looks like you are trying to differentiate between login from desktop or mobile browser. then you should take a look at user-agent header

Comment: @SangamBelose  Distinguish the url in the code should be the best method such as the response below. Accordint to my experience, user-agent could be edit manually by users, so I think that is not the best way. Still thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html#BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE) attribute.

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/weblogin", "/mobilelogin" })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public AccessTokenResponseModel login(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
   final String requestMapping = ( String ) httpRequest.getAttribute( HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE );
   final boolean isMobileLogin = requestMapping.contains("/mobilelogin");

   ....
}
```